# URL parameters appear in the address bar although using POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ROR but I face this problem:
in the index page I have

```
<%= button_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post  %>
```

when user presses the "Yes button" the url that passed to the controller contains all the parameters explicitly to the user.

```
vote?id=1&user_answer=yes
```

in routes.rb I have:

```
match 'vote' => 'polls#vote', :via => :post
```

Any help is appreciated

edit: the entire index.html.erb

### Polls

```
 <% @polls.each do |poll| %>
   <p>
   <%= poll.question %>?
   <%= button_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.yes %>) /
   <%= button_to 'No', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'no' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.no %>)
   </p>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the html that is rendered?

Comment: I've figured out an important issue that I augment the attributes in the url by: `<%= button_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post %>`
but when replacing this code with `<%= button_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote'},{ :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post %>` it dose not find the appropriate action !!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, so I'm adding a bounty to this question to get it solved. Basically what's happening is that when I create a `button_to` with a `put` method, the address bar (in Chrome) shows the parameters I passed in the button. What's different about creating a `button_to` versus a `form`, where the parameters don't show up in the address bar?

Comment: When examining the parameters in the request, I've noticed that the only difference seems to be the utf-8 parameter not being passed, and a commit parameter not being passed...

Comment: Have you tried to do it with AJAX? Its should be very straight forward to do it or you need to send the user the poll show?

Comment: @aardvarkk replacing the button_to with form_tag is the right option for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The default method for button_to is post, so no need to explicitly specify it unless you want to use other verbs (get, put).

If you don't like the params appended to the url, you might want to use a form instead.
Or, just add the form hash to your button_to tag:

```
<%= button_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll.id, :user_answer => 'yes' }, :form => {:data_type => <your choice (html, json)> %>
```

Comment: I suppose changing it to a form is one option, but adding the form hash to the button_to tag didn't seem to help. I just get another parameter showing up in the address bar. Also, when I look at the parameters passed by a form when it's submitted it does not appear to include this hash...

Comment: What is it about a form that makes it so that the parameters don't appear in the address bar?

Comment: A form is a container, button is not. When you submit a form, the attributes are submitted as a hash, in case of a button, html doesn't know how to send the accompanying params, so it just sends the params as a query string